# Is it possible to access a user's GMail account via Gmail API to send/receive emails from within an app using 2-legged oauth?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a native desktop app in C# that currently accesses the GMail API via POP3/SMTP using OAuth 2.0 for email send and receive from within the app. This uses 3-legged OAuth, with the user being redirected to allow access, then the app uses the access token and refresh token received for all future requests.

My question is, can I access any GMail account using 2-legged OAuth, without the redirect? Or is this only possible if the user's email is a domain email listed in a Google Workspace with a service account with domain wide delegation?

I am trying to find a way to use 2-legged OAuth to allow the app to send/receive emails via GMail API without needing user redirect authentication. Is this possible for all GMail accounts?

Comment: So, in other words, you're trying to bypass intentional security features put in place by Google?

Comment: I wasn't questioning your motives, merely pointing out that, on a technical level, you're trying to bypass Google's security features. Google won't grant you use tokens unless the user consents on their consent screen. For that purpose, the redirect is necessary. If it were possible to do what you're asking, the authorization code flow with consent screen would be completely pointless.